# Mysql table with no primary key but a foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have read somewhere here that having primary key in each every table is a good thing to do... Let me say I have two tables "student" and "student_details" and i am using INNODB

"student" has a few columns like - student_id(Primary Key), student_name
"student_details" has a few columns like - student_id(Foreign Key), Address, Phone, Mobile, etc..

Do "student_details" still need a primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether you know it or not, what you are doing is column partitioning the table.  You can have `studentdetails.studentid` be both a primary key and a foreign key.  No problem with that.  So, you can have a primary key in the table.

There are several reasons to do column partitioning, usually related to performance on commonly used columns or to create rows with more than the maximum number of columns.  I doubt either of these apply in your case.

In fact, given the nature of the data, the `studentdetails` table is actually storing a "slowly-changing dimension".  In simpler language, students move, so their address changes.  Students change their telephone number.  And so on.  What you should really have is an effective and end date for each student details record.  Then you can add an auto-incrementing primary key (which is what I would do) or you could declare `studentdetails(studentid, effdate)` as the primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gordon... I have read somewhere that setting a column as both foreign and primary key will lead to index duplication which in turn affects the performance... i am not sure though... will it work that way?

Comment: @user27841 . . . The `primary key` element does create an index on the column.  The `foreign key` does not (the index is created on the `student` table).  If you declared it instead as a unique foreign key, you would then get an index (similar in spirit to the primary key index).  To be honest, this is not a data structure that I would use very often for a 1-1 relationship, although it is more common for a 1-0/1 relationship.